# Angular 7 - *ngFor not iterating properly and not considering de-structured object

Tags: javascript, angular

```
let package = [{
    "masterPack": [{
        "itemName": "master value",
        "grams": "100",
        "rate": "5",
        "scheme": "ccc"
    }],
    "boostPack": [{
        "itemName": "beginner value",
        "grams": "50",
        "rate": "3",
        "scheme": "ccc"
    }]
}];
```

**Attempt 1 : straight forward**

```
const itemName = package[0].masterPack[0].itemName + ' + ' + package[0].boostPack[0].itemName;
    const grams = Number(res[0].masterPack[0].grams) + Number(res[0].boostPack[0].grams);
    const rate = Number(res[0].masterPack[0].rate) + Number(res[0].boostPack[0].rate);
    const scheme = package[0].masterPack[0].scheme;
    this.mergeAll.push({
        itemName,
        grams,
        rate,
        scheme,
    }, ...this.package[0].masterPack);
    console.error('final', this.mergeAll);
```

**Attempt 2 : for-loop**

```
for (let i = 0; i < package[0].masterPack.length; i++) {
    const itemName = package[0].masterPack[i].itemName + ' + ' + package[0].boostPack[i].itemName;
    const grams = Number(res[0].masterPack[i].grams) + Number(res[0].boostPack[i].grams);
    const rate = Number(res[0].masterPack[i].rate) + Number(res[0].boostPack[i].rate);
    const scheme = package[0].masterPack[i].scheme;
    this.mergeAll.push({
        itemName,
        grams,
        rate,
        scheme,
    }, ...this.package[0].masterPack);
    console.error('final', this.mergeAll);
}
```

Here i'm trying to show two div as follow

```
  <div *ngFor="data of mergeAll">
            <div class="one">
                special offer: master Edition + beginner value // ex: masterPack.itemName + '+' addOnPack.itemName
                total grams : 107 // ex: masterPack.grams + '+' addOnPack.grams
                total price(no gst) : Rs 8 // ex: masterPack.rate + '+' addOnPack.rate
                you purchased under : ccc ex: masterPack.scheme
            </div>
            <div class="two">
        
                Default offer: master Edition // ex: masterPack.itemName
                total grams : 107 // ex: masterPack.grams
                total price(no gst) : Rs 8 // ex: masterPack.rate
                you purchased under : ccc ex: masterPack.scheme
            </div>
        </div>
```

**issue:**
I can able to see two objects inside this.mergeAll but if use `*ngFor = "data in mergeAll"`, its not iterating values properly. means, it's not considering `...this.package[0].masterPack`

Could some one tell me how simplify the above two failed attempt to achieve the output.?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You must define data variable first, and use **of** instead of **in**:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of mergeAll">
        <div class="one">
            special offer: master Edition + beginner value // ex: masterPack.itemName + '+' addOnPack.itemName
            total grams : 107 // ex: masterPack.grams + '+' addOnPack.grams
            total price(no gst) : Rs 8 // ex: masterPack.rate + '+' addOnPack.rate
            you purchased under : ccc ex: masterPack.scheme
        </div>
        <div class="two">
    
            Default offer: master Edition // ex: masterPack.itemName
            total grams : 107 // ex: masterPack.grams
            total price(no gst) : Rs 8 // ex: masterPack.rate
            you purchased under : ccc ex: masterPack.scheme
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sorry thats my typo error. its like that only.. updated my question

Answer (score 1):

The below should work for you.

```
<div *ngFor="let data of packag; let i = index" class="special">
  <h1>Special Offer</h1>
    <div>
    Special Offer: {{data.masterPack[i].itemName}} {{data.boostPack[i].itemName}}
    </div>
  <div>
    Total grams: {{sumNumbers(data.masterPack[i].grams, data.boostPack[i].grams)}}
    </div>
  <div>
    Total price(no gst): {{sumNumbers(data.masterPack[i].rate, data.boostPack[i].rate)}}
    </div>
  <div>
    You purchased under: {{data.masterPack[i].scheme}}
    </div>
  </div>

<div *ngFor="let data of packag; let i = index" class="base">
  <h1>Base Offer</h1>
    <div>
    Special Offer: {{data.masterPack[i].itemName}}
    </div>
  <div>
    Total grams: {{data.masterPack[i].grams}}
    </div>
  <div>
    Total price(no gst): {{data.masterPack[i].rate}}
    </div>
  <div>
    You purchased under: {{data.masterPack[i].scheme}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Method in component.ts

```
sumNumbers(a, b) {
    return Number(a) + Number(b);
  }
```

If you want to have single array, the below loop will create single collection for both special and base offer.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.packag[0].masterPack.length; i++) {
    let itemName = this.packag[0].masterPack[i].itemName + ' + ' + this.packag[0].boostPack[i].itemName;
    let grams = Number(this.packag[0].masterPack[i].grams) + Number(this.packag[0].boostPack[i].grams);
    let rate = Number(this.packag[0].masterPack[i].rate) + Number(this.packag[0].boostPack[i].rate);
    let scheme = this.packag[0].masterPack[i].scheme;
    this.mergeAll.push({
        itemName,
        grams,
        rate,
        scheme,
    });
    itemName = this.packag[0].masterPack[i].itemName;
    grams = Number(this.packag[0].masterPack[i].grams);
    rate = Number(this.packag[0].masterPack[i].rate);
    scheme = this.packag[0].masterPack[i].scheme;
    this.mergeAll.push({
        itemName,
        grams,
        rate,
        scheme,
    });
```

Template

```
<div *ngFor="let data of mergeAll" class="base">
  <h1>{{data.rowType}}</h1>
    <div>
    Special Offer: {{data.itemName}}
    </div>
  <div>
    Total grams: {{data.grams}}
    </div>
  <div>
    Total price(no gst): {{data.rate}}
    </div>
  <div>
    You purchased under: {{data.scheme}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fxztwk?embed=1&file=angular.json

Comment: how to use `sumNumbers``to calculate. can you pls show it in stackblitz?

its seems, there is no need to my above two attempts.!!!

Comment: I have given the stackblitz link. sumNumbers method should be added in ts file. I have give that as well in the answer.

Comment: Yes, understood., just for illustration purpose asked to show two divs, here what actual another challenge i faced is, its supposed to be 1 div that has be iterated with *ngFor

Comment: what is the issue in my code? i dont understand, i just want have single array of object to use *ngFor. so that can avoid using two DIVS

Comment: You can have 2 divs with 2 ngFor. Updated the answer and stackblitz

Comment: Updated the answer to have single array. If you have stackblitz, can you share for your code.

Answer (score 0):

this another way in case you just want to display the packages without update of transfer the data by just using **ngFor** and , **keyvalue** pipe

```js
<ng-container *ngFor="let data of package">
    <div *ngFor="let v of data | keyvalue;">
        <h3>
            {{v.key}}
        </h3>
        <ng-container *ngIf="v.value[0] as item">
            <div>
                <div>
                    itemName : {{item.itemName}}
                </div>
                <div>
                    grams : {{item.grams}}
                </div>
                <div>
                    rate :{{item.rate}}
                </div>
                <div>
                    scheme : {{item.scheme}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

> this line `<ng-container *ngIf="v.value[0] as item">` just to create a variable for v.value[0] so I don't need to keep writing `v.value[0].`.

> another point my answer is just to show that it is possible to use **ngFor** and **keyvalue** pipe to display **package** so this may help to simplify you logic

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ammt48)